# How to make a basic line plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I have

```
a =

   54.1848
   50.0456
   99.9748
   83.1009
   63.1457
   91.7577
   64.0805
   48.2090
   75.7711

t =

   79.7077
   31.0913
   14.9389
   10.8303
   16.4844
   26.8465
   41.6946
   77.3369
  186.3246
```

How can make a simple line plot with `a` on `y axis` and `t` on `x axis`?

`plot (a,t)` gives

[image]

and `plot (t,a)` gives

[image]

I don't understand how these are generated. The result should be something else.

Comment: what is it that you expect? This behaves like the `GL_LINES` in OpenGL

Comment: I know what you're expecting...but you really need to be much more explicit with your question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[t_sorted, index] = sort(t);
plot(t_sorted, a(index));
```

is the most efficient way to do this.

Or, if you don't really care for having the lines you can simply use:

```
plot(t,a,'rx')
```

Comment: One minor point: The OP said they want to plot `t` on the x axis and `a` on the y axis, so you just have to swap the two variables in your code.

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you sort both vectors according to the values in `t` and then use `plot(t,a)` you will get what you want.